# How to sort alphanumeric keys in Hashmap in best possible manner?

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

I have map like

```
Map<String,Integer> mp = new TreeMap<>();
        mp.put("R1", 00);
        mp.put("R0", 11);
        mp.put("R2", 22);
        mp.put("R3", 33);
        mp.put("R5", 55);
        mp.put("R8", 88);
        mp.put("R4", 44);
        mp.put("R6", 66);
        mp.put("R9", 99);
        mp.put("R7", 77);
        mp.put("R11", 1111);
        mp.put("R14", 1414);
        mp.put("R10", 1010);
        mp.put("R12", 1212);
        mp.put("R13", 1313);
        mp.put("R15", 1515);
        mp.put("R17", 1717);
        mp.put("R19", 1919);
```

I want to sort based upon keys. TreeMap is not working because of alphanumeric, getting output

```
{R0=11, R1=0, R10=1010, R11=1111, R12=1212, R13=1313, R14=1414, R15=1515, R17=1717, R19=1919, R2=22, R3=33, R4=44, R5=55, R6=66, R7=77, R8=88, R9=99}
```

Suggest how to do this?

Comment: This is normal ordering for Strings.  If you need to order them differently, use a `Comparator` that compares strings in whatever order you need.

Comment: What order do you want them in?

Comment: I want order like: {R0=11, R1=0, R2=22, R3=33, R4=44..}

Comment: Are all keys in form of `R[number]` or can there be keys like `A[number]` `BB[number]`?

Comment: All in R[Number] only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create and pass to your TreeMap Comparator which will compare only integer part from keys (assuming that all keys are in form of `R[number]`).

In Java 8 your map can look like

```
Map<String, Integer> mp = new TreeMap<>(
        Comparator.comparingInt(key -> Integer.parseInt(key.substring(1))));
```

In Java 7 you can use rewrite it as

```
Map<String, Integer> mp = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<String>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(String key1, String key2) {
               //parse only text after first letter
        int k1 = Integer.parseInt(key1.substring(1));
        int k2 = Integer.parseInt(key2.substring(1));
        return Integer.compare(k1, k2);
    }
});
```

It will order elements in a way:

```
{R0=11, R1=0, R2=22, R3=33, R4=44, R5=55, R6=66, R7=77, R8=88, R9=99, R10=1010, R11=1111, R12=1212, R13=1313, R14=1414, R15=1515, R17=1717, R19=1919}
```

Comment: @TanuGarg I updated my answer to add Java 7 solution.

Comment: ya some import issue was there. Thanks for quick support.

Comment: Note that this solution requires to set the comparator on the constructor of the treeMap, then you will have to set the values of the map

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `Set` of `Entry` object from the `Map`. Then pass a custom `Comparator` to the `Collections.sort()` along with the `Set`. I have give the template below.

```
Set<Entry<String, Integer>> set = map.entrySet();
List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>(set);
Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>()
{
  public int compare( Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2 )
  {
    // Put your logic here for sorting.
  }
} );
```

You can use the `regex` or `substring` method from `String` for separating the chars and numbers from the `String`.